# How do I align elements in adjacent columns of a UL?

Tags: html-lists

How do I align elements in adjacent columns of a ?

How it is not working:

[image]

Have tried specifying a fixed height to ul li {} which does the aligning; however, when the height needed is very small, this leaves huge white space.

HTML = standard

CSS =

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;   /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:    2;   /* Firefox */
    column-count:         2;
}

ul li {
    color:         red;     /* bullet color */
    padding-right: 2.0em;   /* not too close */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't written your html code but try to put ul tag in a div tag. you can play with div's height and width

Comment: I returned to display: table and table-cell for ul and li.  Yes, it does work, but I feel "dirty" because it's like writing TABLE, TR etc again!!